# Conditional Formatting: Why does this only work in one cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've got some conditional formatting which works when "applies too" is a single cell, whenever I try and expand the format to additional cells only the original cell takes the format.

[image: Example]

I'm using: `=M20=1` `then` `format cell "red"`

This works when the applied too is `=$C$21` but not when it's `=$C$21:$F$21`

I'm probably being dumb, sorry in advance, thank you.

Comment: @ScottCraner it does! that's about the only thing I didn't try, thank you. I've been losing my mind today. Please submit as an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the range to use the same cell as its criteria then the cell must be absolute:

```
=$M$20=1
```

Other wise for `D21` it will be looking at `N20` not `M21`